# How to get channel name in incoming message using only Telegram Bot API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm working on one Telegram bot and faced a big problem: In order to exlude some "fraud" things one can do with my bot, I need to verify whether a user is admin in some channel or not. However, if user forward message from channel to bot, `Chat.type` parameter is still `private`, not `channel`.

Is there any way to get a pair `user_id <--> in which channel user_id can post` using only Bot API? Unfortunately, Inline mode doesn't help at all too.

Of course, I can use Telegram CLI for that, but in this particular situation it's prohibited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of May 6, 2016, a new field `forward_from_chat` is added to `Message` object. So my problem is solved.

More info about `Message` object: [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message)